# How to store sed arguments in variable for parameter substitution in BASH

Tags: bash, shell, sed, parameter-expansion

I need to store some sed expressions in a variable and substitute it in the sed command.

```
myArgs="-e 's/foo/bar/' -e 's/foo2/bar2/'"
```

So far these are not working:

```
echo "foo" | sed ${myArgs} 
# sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

echo "foo" | sed  $(echo ${myArgs})
# sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

echo ${myArgs}
's/foo/bar/' -e 's/foo2/bar2/'
# 1st -e missing
```

Parameter expansion interprets the first -e argument in the variable.

-e may be interpreted as a test for exist, or argument to echo.

How can I prevent this and use it literally for the sed command?

To clarify, this is just a simplified version of a command that will contain a large number of sed expressions with characters that require escaping in the regex, and I would rather keep the expressions quoted as-is, and dump all the sed expressions into the sed command as a single variable.

If that's not possible, I'll use a different method such as the current answers below, however it seems there should be some built in bash method to not pre-expand the variable, and instead just interpret it as a string, before it's used in the final sed command.

The actual arguments I'm using will look something like this:

```
-e 's/^>chr1.*/>NC_032089.1_chr1/' -e 's/^>chr2.*/>NC_032090.1_chr2/'
```

With unknown strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a string, use an array:

```
myArgs=("-e" "s/foo/bar/" "-e" "s/foo2/bar2/")
sed "${myArgs[@]}" <<< "foo"
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a simplified version of something I'm already trying to use, and I'd prefer not to have to refactor the other stuff if possible.

Comment: I ended up using a combination of both of the above answers however I'm accepting yours because the redirection was something I hadn't thought of

Answer (score 1):

Since we know the input, and the `sed` code is safe enough, it's OK to use [`eval`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash#23117) here:

```
echo foo | eval sed $myArgs
```

Output:

```
bar
```

---

Related Q. about things to be wary of:  [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)

*Mo Budlong*'s Sunworld column [Command line psychology 101](http://www.kingcomputerservices.com/unix_101/command_line_psychology_101.htm) is the most helpful thing I've seen for understanding command line parsing.

Comment: Thanks.  The real input is unknown, and will contain other characters that could break eval.  Eval could potentially work, but I was hoping there was some way to do the substitution without interpreting -e

Comment: Well, one might parse `$myArgs` in advance and quit if anything dangerous was found.  The input (*e.g.* "foo" here) shouldn't matter.